# Integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5 + 4x - x^3}}$

Tags: integration

I have attempted this. I tried factorising $-x^3 + 4x + 5$ in order to bring this to the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}$ but haven't been able to.

Comment: My guess: it's a typo. I suspect that the $x^3$ term is supposed to be an $x^2$ term.

Comment: To emphasize the above point, not even Wolfram is really sure what to make of it ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2Fsqrt%285%2B4x-x%5E3%29)), whereas for $x^2$ instead you can easily manipulate the integrand to get an arcsine function as a result of the integration